# Why does my code return the type of the object instead of its value?

Tags: c#

I created a new class and used an operator in it

```
class blabla
{
    public static implicit operator blabla(int val)
    {
        return new blabla();
    }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        blabla x = 15;

        Console.WriteLine(x);

        Console.Read();
    }

}
```

But my program prints out ConsoleApplication1.blabla instead of 15. Why?

Comment: Because that's what `ToString()` -- which is implicitly called when you do a `Console.WriteLine` -- does with an instance of a class that hasn't overridden `ToString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a [conversion operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) with this code:

```
public static implicit operator blabla(int val)
{
    return new blabla();
}
```

This code converts an `int` to a `blabla` but your code ignores `val` completely. You probably want to pass it to the new `blabla` instance.

Maybe you want something like this:

```
class blabla
{
    protected int val;
    public blabla(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
    public static implicit operator blabla(int val)
    {
        return new blabla(val);
    }
    public override string ToString() {
        return val.ToString();
    }
}
```

This calls the conversion operator and creates a new `blabla` with the passed in value.

Also, it overrides `ToString()` which is what gets called by `Console.WriteLine`. If you don't override that, you get the default - which is what you are seeing in your output.

However, this seems overly complicated. Why not delete the conversion operator and just call the constructor directly?

```
static void Main()
{
    blabla x = new blabla(15);
    Console.WriteLine(x);
    Console.Read();
}
```